# Trying to do a very small GoogleSheet custom function for a very niche "problem" that i have. Can't seem to make it work

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

It's my first time doing a Google Sheet function + i don't really know JavaScript, and I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

What I want to do is a function that does the following:

If the selected cell *example* **A1** has the **X** value, then make another cell *example* **C5** have the **Y** value.
The only clue I got is that I can change a cell's value using the .setValue("value") and the y usually do it with the .getRange() but they use an exact point in the sheet. Which I don't like.

This is what i got.

```
function REMWRITE(sheetname, cellCheck, valueCheck, cellWrite, valueWrite) {
  
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var val1 = targetSheet. getRange(cellCheck).getValue();
  var val2 = valueCheck;
  if(val1 == val2)
  {
    targetSheet.getRange(cellWrite).setValue("Tumor");
  }
}
```

As I recently found out, apparently there is no way to change a cell with the set Value in the way I want. Sad. People usually do it executing the command from the code editor.

Comment: From `Trying to do a very small GoogleSheet custom function for a very niche "problem" that i have. Can't seem to make it work`, when you want to use your showing script as a custom function, `setValue` cannot be used. Please be careful about this. And, in your situation, how do you use your script? When your sample situation is used, where cell do you want to put the custom function?

Comment: As a matter of interest, what cell did you propose to apply this formula? As it is written (and even if you could use `setValue`), the function would be dynamic. Change the value in `cellCheck` and the function would re-calculate. I wonder, is this an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/399653) - the focus is on your attempted solution rather than on your "problem". +1 for the information request by @Tanaike.